# Middleware order Express

Tags: node.js, express, helmet.js

According to the [**Security Best Practices**](http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html) by Express, I implemented `Helmet`.

As I am using multiple middlewares (`cookie-session`, `morgan`, `body-parser` and various self-made middlewares for authentication), I'm now wondering in which order I should put them.
Is there a **best practice guide for middlewares**, their security and order?

Comment: I don't know of a general best practice—I think it depends on the middleware. For example, you might want to put Morgan first so it logs all requests and never gets skipped.

Comment: @EvanHahn Yes, but what is with `helmet`? As it is checking all request for potential vulnerabilities, shouldn't it be even before `morgan`?

Comment: We can talk more on the [Helmet GitHub issue](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/issues/144).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I'd use helmet as the first middleware.

The most important reason for this is the HSTS handling. This will handle the bit where users are FORCED to use the HTTPS version of your site, instead of the plain HTTP one.

Not listing Helmet first on an HTTPS site could lead to some interesting vulnerabilities, because users could potentially start a transaction over HTTP, passing sensitive information to your webapp which can be used maliciously, THEN have their request later redirect to HTTPS via Helmet (not good).

This is an interesting question, and this should definitely be added to the Helmet docs.

Comment: I'm going to make an issue in Helmets repo on GitHub.

Comment: See the newly-created [Helmet GitHub issue](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/issues/144).

Comment: Super awesome. Really fast resolution as well. +1 awesome project / great maintainer.